# Using proxy with another SSL certificate when connecting to app

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, single-sign-on

There is an app that has configured a SSO throughout Keycloack server (Keycloack is mine). Let's assume that you can reach the app via https://www.example.domain.com. Now, I don't have access to the app directly but I would like to make it available at my own domain, which is https://www.domain.another.com (this is agreed with app owner). To do that I've tried to establish a proxy server, which will serve my ssl and forward request to [www.example.domain.com](http://www.example.domain.com). But problematic part is SSO, because after successful login, it redirects to https://www.example.domain.com instead of https://www.domain.another.com. I'm not an expert in this, but how this should be configured, so that when request is coming from proxy, it should be redirect to proxy base url? One thing: I don't want to share private key of my domain with app owner.

For the proxy I use Nginx with following config:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name http://www.domain.another.com;

        ssl_password_file /home/keys/file.pass;
        ssl_certificate /home/keys/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/keys/tls.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.example.domain.com;          
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }

   
    }
  }
```